# Easiest way to query a form on a website and extract data to excel?

Tags: html, excel, web, webforms, export-to-excel

I’m not friendly with coding. I am looking for an easy/free way to search for multiple user-provided queries that need to be filled up on a website, and the results for all queries displayed at the website, stored in an excel file.

I’m currently searching for each query manually using my web browser and copy-pasting the needed data to an excel table which makes the job quite tedious.

Answer (score 2):

The question is not very clear but as far as I can understand, you want to save web form data to a spreadsheet. You can do this using an API Spreadsheets tool. Here're the steps to follow:

1. Set up a contact form in an HTML file
2. Prepare your spreadsheet that the data will be saved to & write column headers equal to the names of the  tags
3. Go to [www.apispreadsheets.com](http://www.apispreadsheets.com), upload the spreadsheet file and copy the API URL for your file to use it in javascript.
4. Configure your Javascript file to submit data from the form.
   In the script, include the FULL jQuery library. Then, Write the SubForm() function & replace the URL below with the URL you obtained
   Here's an example of the script part. Hope, it explains a lot:

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
function SubForm (){
    $.ajax({
        url:'https://api.apispreadsheets.com/data/410/',
        type:'post',
        data:$("#myForm").serializeArray(),
        success: function(){
          alert("Form Data Submitted :)")
        },
        error: function(){
          alert("There was an error :(")
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: By web-form I meant a form that we have to query on a website. So basically I search a stamp number on a third-party website, and it provides details corresponding to the stamp number. I want to save that to spreadsheet using an automated process because I have about 500 stamp numbers.